# Define Unique ID for combinations Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data which looks like below table.

```
grp      dpt    cls  lvl
Grp1                  0
Grp1    dpt1          1
Grp1    dpt2          1 
Grp1    dpt1    cs1   2
Grp1    dpt1    cs2   2
Grp1    dpt2    cs1   2
Grp1    dpt2    cs2   2
Grp1    dpt2    cs3   2
```

I have combinations of grp, dpt, cls and levels has been assigned based on position.
This list might vary depending on the user selection from front end.

what I want to do is to assign an unique ID for the combinations like below table.(SNO)

```
grp      dpt     cls  lvl   SNO
Grp1                   0    0
Grp1    dpt1           1    1
Grp1    dpt2           1    2
Grp1    dpt1    cs1    2    11
Grp1    dpt1    cs2    2    12
Grp1    dpt2    cs1    2    21
Grp1    dpt2    cs2    2    22
Grp1    dpt2    cs3    2    23
```

Here I have only one grp so the SNO is 0.

2 unique dpt so the SNO are 1 and 2 respectively.

depending on the dpt1 the respective cls will have SNO 11, 12 for the dpt of 1.

depending on the dpt2 the respective cls will have SON 21, 22 for the dpt of 2.

```
IF USER SELECT ONE MORE HIERARCHY AFTER CLS THEN THE NEXT LEVEL OF HIERARCHY WILL HAVE SNO's DEPENDING ON THE CLS VALUES. EG (111, 112, 113  or 121, 122, 123)
```

User can select GRP, DPT, CLS, or any other combination also from front end so the data will change accordingly.

All I want is to make the process dynamic to assign SNO's.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the SNO column you want, but if you want the number at the end to be the category value, you can use `df.str.split` to split it, then join the three columns together and make it an integer. The result will be 100,110,120,111,112,121,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lists=['GRP','DPT','CLS']


grpNM = pd.DataFrame({lists[0]: df[lists[0]].unique()})

grpNM['SN_lvl'] = grpNM.index+1

df = df.merge(grpNM, how='left', on=lists[0])

df['SN_lvl'] = df['SN_lvl'].fillna(0)

df['SN_lvl'] = df['SN_lvl'].astype(int)

df['SNO'] = df['SN_lvl'].astype(str)

df.drop(['SN_lvl'], inplace=True, axis=1)

#FOR FIRST LEVEL ID ASSIGNMENT DONE MANUALLY 

#1st LEVEL OF ID ASSIGNMENT DONE MANUALLY WITHOUT RUUNING THE LOOP


#NEXT LEVELS ID CREATION HAS BEEN DONE INSIDE LOOP

sn_list = df['SNO'].unique()

tempF = pd.DataFrame()

l1=lists.copy()
l1=l1[1:]
print(l1)

for L in range(len(l1)):
    for i in sn_list:
    
        tempDF = pd.DataFrame({l1[L]: df[df['SNO'] == i][l1[L]].unique()[1:]})
    
        tempDF['SN_lvl'] = tempDF.index+1
        
        tempDF['SN_lvl'].astype(int)
        
        tempDF['SNO'] = i
    
        tempF = tempF.append(tempDF, ignore_index=False) 
        
    df = df.merge(tempF, how='left', on=['SNO',l1[L]])
    
    df['SN_lvl'] = df['SN_lvl'].astype('O')    
    df.loc[df['SN_lvl'].notnull(), 'SN_lvl'] = df.loc[df['SN_lvl'].notnull(), 'SN_lvl'].astype(int)
    
    df['SN_lvl'] = df['SN_lvl'].fillna('')
    
    df['SNO'] = df['SNO'] + df['SN_lvl'].astype(str)
    
    df.drop(['SN_lvl'], inplace=True, axis=1)  
    
    sn_list = df['SNO'].unique()[1:]
```

Used this approach to get the goal.
Used List as i wanted to make it dynamic based on the list passed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

`SNO` is combination of the numbers at the end of each of the columns from column no 1 to the second last column. You can combine all these columns and extract the numbers occuring at the end using regex. (Otherwise a loop would be required to go over all the columns). Concatenating with `##` to just determine the number occurring at end of the value of each of these columns

```
df['SNO'] = (df.iloc[:, 1:-1] # this will take all the columns after grp and before lvl
             .apply(lambda x: "##".join(x.values.astype(str))+"##", axis=1)
             .str.extractall(r'(?P<SNO>\d+)##') # extract all the numbers before ##
             .groupby(level=0)['SNO'].apply(lambda x: "".join(list(x))))

     grp    dpt     cls  lvl   SNO
0   Grp1                 0     NaN
1   Grp1    dpt1         1     1
2   Grp1    dpt2         1     2
3   Grp1    dpt1    cs1  2     11
4   Grp1    dpt1    cs2  2     12
5   Grp1    dpt2    cs1  2     21
6   Grp1    dpt2    cs2  2     22
7   Grp1    dpt2    cs3  2     23
```

The first row of `SNO` would be needed to fill with the `group no - 1`

```
df['SNO'] = df['SNO'].fillna((df['grp'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$').astype(int)-1)[0])

     grp    dpt     cls lvl SNO
0   Grp1                0   0
1   Grp1    dpt1        1   1
2   Grp1    dpt2        1   2
3   Grp1    dpt1    cs1 2   11
4   Grp1    dpt1    cs2 2   12
5   Grp1    dpt2    cs1 2   21
6   Grp1    dpt2    cs2 2   22
7   Grp1    dpt2    cs3 2   23
```

#### Intermediate steps outputs:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:-1].apply(lambda x: "##".join(x.values.astype(str))+"##", axis=1)

0    ####       
1    dpt1####   
2    dpt2####   
3    dpt1##cs1##
4    dpt1##cs2##
5    dpt2##cs1##
6    dpt2##cs2##
7    dpt2##cs3##
dtype: object

(df.iloc[:, 1:-1].apply(lambda x: "##".join(x.values.astype(str))+"##", axis=1)
 .str.extractall(r'(?P<SNO>\d+)##'))

        SNO
  match 
1   0   1
2   0   2
3   0   1
    1   1
4   0   1
    1   2
5   0   2
    1   1
6   0   2
    1   2
7   0   2
    1   3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a map for every column's content to unique number
col_map = dict()
col_map['grp'] = {'Grp1':'0'}
for col in ['dpt', 'cls']:
    cond = df[col] != ''
    obj = df.loc[cond, col].sort_values().dropna().unique()
    col_map[col] = dict(zip(obj, map(str,range(1, len(obj)+1))))

col_map
# {'grp': {'Grp1': '0'},
#  'dpt': {'dpt1': '1', 'dpt2': '2'},
#  'cls': {'cs1': '1', 'cs2': '2', 'cs3': '3'}}

# map with col_map content to number
for col in col_map:
    df[col+'_m'] = df[col].map(col_map[col])
df = df.fillna('')

df['tag'] = df[['grp_m','dpt_m','cls_m']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1).map(list)
df['lvl'] = df['lvl'].astype(int)
df['SNO'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.tag[-x.lvl:]), axis=1)

print(df)

#     grp   dpt  cls  lvl grp_m dpt_m cls_m        tag SNO
# 0  Grp1               0     0                    [0]   0
# 1  Grp1  dpt1         1     0     1           [0, 1]   1
# 2  Grp1  dpt2         1     0     2           [0, 2]   2
# 3  Grp1  dpt1  cs1    2     0     1     1  [0, 1, 1]  11
# 4  Grp1  dpt1  cs2    2     0     1     2  [0, 1, 2]  12
# 5  Grp1  dpt2  cs1    2     0     2     1  [0, 2, 1]  21
# 6  Grp1  dpt2  cs2    2     0     2     2  [0, 2, 2]  22
# 7  Grp1  dpt2  cs3    2     0     2     3  [0, 2, 3]  23
```